# How to prevent empty String in VB/ASP.Net function parameter

Tags: vb.net, parameters, string

How would I prevent other developers from enter "" or " " into the following function/sub?

```
Public Sub MyFunction(MyString as String)

End Sub

' Call:
MyFunction("")
```

I want them to end up with a non compileable app.

Comment: I don't think that the content of a string is available at compile time.

Comment: Well, I'm not talking about string variables but rather hardcoded strings, e.g. "This is going in"

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent compilation based on what is passed to the string.  You can, however, simply prevent the method from executing, like this:

```
Public Sub MyFunction(myString as String)
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(myString) Then
        ' Do stuff here
    End If 
End Sub
```

Your other option is to throw an exception:

```
Public Sub MyFunction(myString as String)
    If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(myString) Then
        Throw New ApplicationException("No empty or whitespace strings allowed!")
    Else
        ' Do stuff here
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, OK, I see I can't achieve what I want. This way the end user would get the message. I don't want this. Thank you anyway!